# Can I create .ipa file and send it to my customer without apple developer program

Tags: provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate, xcode8.2

I am new to ios programming and want to clear some question and problem which I am facing while extrating ipa file.

> 1. Can I extract .ipa file throw xcode without having developer program but i have developer id and create .ipa file throw PayLoad Process?
> 2. How much I am able to do without apple Developer Program?
> 3. I want to show progress to my customer, what is the solution?
> 4. I am getting Signing Certificate and auto-generate provisioning profiles errors while extracting .ipa file, Are these problem coming because of not having developer programming?
> 5. Can I send ipa file to anyone to install and check?

Comment: [Search for your exact title](https://www.google.de/search?q=Can+I+create+.ipa+file+and+send+it+to+my+customer+without+apple+developer+program&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VVXmWLa2DIig8we3rJbwAQ)

Comment: I want to do this in xcode 8, i have seen and read many answers from various website but still i am not clear, if you  can explain, please explain my questions.

Comment: Sorry. [Search for your exact title plus Xcode8](https://www.google.de/search?q=Can+I+create+.ipa+file+and+send+it+to+my+customer+without+apple+developer+program&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VVXmWLa2DIig8we3rJbwAQ#q=xcode8+Can+I+create+.ipa+file+and+send+it+to+my+customer+without+apple+developer+program)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no.  The free apple developer account only allows you to deploy your application on a device that is plugged into the Mac.  If you need to send an IPA to someone else for installing onto their device, you need a full developer account (paid).  You'll also need them to send you the UDID of the device so you can manually add it to your device list / profile in Apple's developer portal.

If you want to demonstrate progress, I would share your screen through any number of online meeting solutions, and demonstrate the app in the simulator.  Or you can record the screen of an actual device in Quicktime and send them the video.